# Не работают валидаторы

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtf

Не могу понять, почему не работают валидаторы(Все обновлено до новейшей версии)

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, current_app, g, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_script import Manager, Command
from json import load, dump
from random import randint
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import (DataRequired, Email, Length, Required, EqualTo)


class RegisterLoginForm(FlaskForm):
    new_name = StringField('Login', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3)])
    new_psw = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, message="not less than 6")])
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[Email(check_deliverability=True, message="seeming email"), DataRequired()])
    equal_psw = PasswordField("Repeat your password", validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo("new_psw")])
    name = StringField('Login', validators=[DataRequired()])
    psw = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Enter")


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
manager = Manager(app)


@app.route("/register", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
form = RegisterLoginForm()
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template('reg.html', form=form)
else:
    with open("db.json", 'r') as f:
        db = load(f)

    new_login = form.new_name.data
    new_password = form.new_psw.data
    new_email = form.email.data
    db.append({"login": new_login, "password": new_password, "id": randint(3, 10000), "email": new_email})
    with open('db.json', 'w') as f:
        dump(db, f)
    print('Удачная регистрация пользователя ' + new_login)
    return render_template('reg.html', mess="Удачная регистрация", form=form)
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container my-class"><div align="center"><h1>Регистрация</h1></div>
        {{ mess }}
        <form method="post" action="/register" class="form-contact">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.new_name.label() }}<br>
            {{ form.new_name() }}<br>
            {{ form.new_psw.label() }}<br>
            {{ form.new_psw() }}<br>
            {{ form.equal_psw.label }}<br>
            {{ form.equal_psw }}<br>
            {{ form.email.label() }}<br>
            {{ form.email() }}<br><br>
            {{ form.submit() }}
        </form>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не осуществляется валидация в коде, хотя правила валидации описаны. Попробуйте так:

```
if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template('reg.html', form=form)
else:            
    if form.validate_on_submit():    
        with open("db.json", 'r') as f:
            db = load(f)
        new_login = form.new_name.data
        new_password = form.new_psw.data
        new_email = form.email.data
        db.append({"login": new_login, "password": new_password, "id": randint(3, 10000), "email": new_email})
        with open('db.json', 'w') as f:
            dump(db, f)        
        return render_template('reg.html', mess="Удачная регистрация", form=form)
    else:
        mess = "Ошибка"
        return render_template('reg.html', mess=mess, form=form)
```